# Passing props of click event inside new component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

When I use standard button with onClick props event it works perfectly fine

```
<Button onClick={handleClose}>
            Agree
</Button>
```

But I have also created my new component called `ButtonSave` and onClick is not working

```
<ButtonSave text="Agree" onClick={handleClose} />
```

My code inside `ButtonSave` component

```
export default function IconLabelButtons(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        size={props.size}
        className={classes.button}
        startIcon={<SaveIcon />}
      >
        {props.text}
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

How am I supposed to use my `handleClose` right there?

Comment: You should show the implementation, we can't guess it

Comment: Share your component code

Comment: Yeah, sorry - updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your `ButtonSave` component and pass the `onClick` prop to it like:

```
export default function IconLabelButtons(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        size={props.size}
        className={classes.button}
        startIcon={<SaveIcon />}
        onClick={props.onClick}
      >
        {props.text}
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `onClick` which provided in props:

```
// <ButtonSave text="Agree" onClick={handleClose} />

const ButtonSave = ({ onClick, text }) => (
  <Button onClick={onClick}>{text}</Button>
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on the code you provided, it may be because you didn't pass it from `ButtonSave` to its child of `Button`. So:

```
export default function(props) {
  return (
    <Button onClick={props.handleClose} />
  );
}
```